# find special characters in filenames and copy them into new folder. filenames may contain weird non ascii characters and special ones

Tags: grep, find, xargs

I like to copy all files with special character "｜" in filenames (not the pipe one) into a folder.
However, i have several problems cause filenames may include ascii and not ascii characters, single and double quotes, or special characters  eg. *%& etc.
Xargs prints errors when use -print0 and -0. If i dont use these, xargs says unmatched single quotes.

Dont know what to do.

```
find .  -type f -print0 | grep -i "｜"   | xargs -0 cp {} ident/
grep: binary file matches
cp: cannot stat '{}':
```

Here is a sampel of filenames...

```
Tus\ -\ Οπλοπολυβόλο\ ft\ Μάριος\ Τσιτσόπουλος\ -\ Official\ Video\ Clip\ [PBfXwWeZMMs].webm
Tus\ -\ Όσα\ δε\ σου\ 'χα\ πει\ Prod.\ John\ Thanos\ -\ Official\ Audio\ Release\ [BPn8Ec-V2sE].webm
TUS\ -\ Όσο\ μ'\ αρέσει\ (2000)\ ｜\ TUS\ -\ Oso\ m\ aresei\ (2000)\ [0Rk0s_lm400].webm
Tus\ -\ Ούτε\ Για\ Ζήτω\ ｜\ Oute\ Gia\ Zito\ -\ Official\ Video\ Clip\ [5O26LLx8P2M].webm
Tus\ -\ Πεθαίνουν\ Για\ Μένα\ Prod.\ Dennis\ Cage\ -\ Official\ Audio\ Release\ [RXcHhAStC9E].webm
Tus\ -\ Πεθαίνουν\ Για\ Μένα\ Prod.\ Dennis\ Cage\ -\ Official\ Video\ Clip\ [FGMXALlsxw8].webm
Tus\ -\ Πιτσιρικάκι\ Remix\ prod.\ Άρχοντας\ [sKykzuIesio].mp4
Tus\ -\ Πιτσιρικάκι\ Remix\ prod.\ Άρχοντας\ [sKykzuIesio].webm
Tus\ -\ Που\ είναι\ τα\ λεφτά\ ｜\ Tus\ -\ Pou\ einai\ ta\ lefta\ -\ Official\ Video\ Clip\ [-FO3JcGRrfY].webm
Tus\ -\ Πρώτος\ Στα\ Trends\ Prod.\ Jumper\ -\ Official\ Video\ Clip\ [QOEGjsuchJk].webm
TUS\ -\ Πρώτος\ στο\ σχολείο\ -\ Music\ Μαρία\ Γιαννίκου\ Prod.\ Stoic-\ Official\ Video\ Clip\ [OcArxVsbsP0].webm
Tus\ -\ Πως\ Tus\ Prod.\ Dennis\ Cage\ [umYraDKf7zs].webm
Tus\ -\ Ραπ\ εμπορικό\ κάλαντο\ [wqTZfqzRiqg].webm
Tus\ -\ Ρε\ Μανα\ prod.\ Jusa\ Riddim\ (#onetake\ video)\ [9TnNqO6ejo8].webm
Tus\ -\ Ρούφα\ το\ τρομπόνι\ Prod.\ Fus\ Guest\ Star\ Emilia\ Barak\ -\ Official\ Video\ Clip\ [pIa1BcHROW0].webm
Tus\ &\ Σάκης\ Βέρρος\ -\ Μόνη\ -\ Prod\ Fus\ -\ Official\ Video\ Clip\ [jarzXp8PG9I].webm
Tus\ -\ Σάττι\ Μαρίνα\ ｜\ Tus\ -\ Satti\ Marina\ \ -\ Official\ Audio\ Release\ [lko2Hbph4z4].webm
TUS\ -\ Σε\ θέλω\ (2000)\ ｜\ TUS\ -\ Se\ thelo\ (2000)\ [iTHQkjMO3x4].webm
Tus\ &\ Σεξπυρ\ -\ Μουνάρα\ μεν\ αλλά\ πουτάνα\ ｜\ Tus\ &\ Sexpyr\ -\ Mounara\ Men\ Alla\ Poutana\ [I0zsTpXlhoI].webm
Tus\ &\ Σεξπυρ\ -\ Περνάω\ μηνύματα\ ｜\ Tus\ &\ Sexpyr\ -\ Pernaw\ minimata\ [hDUJpHYVy5A].webm
Tus\ -\ Σουβλάκι\ Κλαρίνο\ &\ Freddo\ Cappuccino\ Prod.\ John\ Thanos\ -\ Official\ Video\ Clip\ [wvGOtnKMmD8].webm
Tus\ -\ στο\ STAR\ κουτσομπολιό\ να\ γίνεται\ [-YmSmDc8Rjw].webm
Tus\ στο\ Your\ Face\ Sounds\ familiar\ by\ Ματθίλδη\ Μαγγίρα\ [6omhM-paNtk].webm
Tus\ -\ Στοματικό\ στον\ Νικόλα\ -\ live\ στο\ Μαρούσι\ ｜\ Tus\ -\ Stomatiko\ Ston\ Nikola\ -\ Live\ Sto\ Marousi\ [u5FzJLtr92M].webm
TUS\ -\ Συνέντευξη\ στο\ Mad\ Day\ Live\ ｜\ TUS-\ Interview\ at\ Mad\ Day\ Live\ [PGHPcwNobLM].webm
TUS\ -\ Σχετικά\ με\ το\ τραγούδι\ βουλγάρες\ [Zc7m-kwSAok].webm
Tus\ -\ Σώτης\ Βολάνης\ -\ Άραβας\ θέλω\ να\ γίνω\ (Fus\ RmX)\ -\ Lyric\ Video\ [t76ncm-XzYU].webm
Tus\ -\ Τα\ Nike\ Prod.\ Minelli\ -\ Official\ Video\ Clip\ [_-MonH-qfBs].webm
Tus\ -\ Τα\ κακά\ κορίτσια\ (prod.\ John\ Thanos)\ -\ Official\ Audio\ Release\ [_ShvOJ4n78I].webm
Tus\ -\ Τάμα\ ft\ \ Γωγώ\ Τσαμπά\ -\ Official\ Audio\ Release\ [jj0ETUs5ykQ].webm
Tus\ -\ Τα\ Παιδιά\ Στη\ Γειτονιά\ prod.\ Dennis\ Cage\ ｜\ Official\ Video\ Clip\ [8bpiW3r3Na0].webm
Tus\ -\ Τα\ Φυτά\ Prod.\ Fus\ -\ Official\ Video\ Clip\ [1Jk03sTptsk].webm
Tus\ -\ Τελευταία\ Φορά\ Prod.\ Strazdine\ -\ Official\ Video\ Clip\ [xoaA673qYzk].webm
Tus\ -\ Τι\ Θέλεις\ Να\ Κάνω\ Prod.\ Minelli\ -\ Official\ Video\ Clip\ [wdrZileylN8].webm
TUS\ -\ \ 'Το\ αντίθετο\ ακριβώς'\ -\ Mad\ Day\ Live\ [KPuojlPOVYw].webm
TUS\ -\ \ ＂Το\ αντίθετο\ ακριβώς＂\ -\ Mad\ Day\ Live\ [KPuojlPOVYw].webm
Tus\ -\ Το\ Καπέλο\ Μου\ ｜\ To\ Kapelo\ Mou\ -\ Official\ Lyric\ Video\ [iWpBXwGGTbU].webm
TUS\ -\ ΤΟ\ ΚΟΥΜΠΙ\ PROD\ STOIC\ \ ｜\ \ TUS\ -\ TO\ KOUMPI\ PROD.\ STOIC\ [KGLm0JcARvM].webm
Tus\ -\ Το\ μνι\ -\ Live\ στο\ Γκάζι\ [SHn8lIv0d44].webm
TUS\ -\ Το\ ταξίδι\ που\ διάλεξες\ (2000)\ ｜\ TUS\ -\ To\ taksidi\ pou\ dialekses\ (2000)\ [ts-SEBjjRuA].webm
Tus\ -\ Το\ Χαπάκι\ ft\ \ Λευτέρης\ Βαζαίος\ -\ Official\ Audio\ Release\ [aElkC3VpsfE].webm
Tus\ -\ Τραγικό\ Φινάλε\ (Bάλε,\ Βάλε)\ -\ Official\ Audio\ Release\ [vgEVVKzbAdY].webm
Tus\ -\ Τσι\ -\ γκάνι\ Prod.\ John\ Thanos\ -\ Official\ Audio\ Release\ [XPRq7sMrBco].webm
Tus\ -\ Τσι\ -\ γκάνι\ Prod.\ John\ Thanos\ -\ Official\ Video\ Clip\ [K5bU4Vzbfps].webm
Tus\ -\ Τσίπρας\ Αλέξης\ ｜\ Tsipras\ Alexis\ -\ Official\ Audio\ Release\ [EKYEDxTzhr8].webm
Tus\ &\ Ύποπτος\ &\ Άρχοντας\ -\ Είμαι\ Χαρμάνης\ -\ Official\ Audio\ Release\ [JuoheCbO2DI].webm
Tus\ -\ Υστεροφημία\ Prod.\ Dennis\ Cage\ [HCJPuUfiH-M].webm
Tus\ -\ Φάντασμα\ ft\ \ Μαρία\ Γιαννίκου\ -\ Official\ Audio\ Release\ [d_pIsZKakgY].webm
Tus\ -\ Φιδίσιο\ Freestyle\ ｜\ Tus\ Fidisio\ Freestyle\ [J2rR7NVMppc].mp4
Tus\ -\ Φιλάκια\ -\ Official\ Audio\ Release\ [9oWXk788-i4].webm
TUS\ -\ (Φώτης\ και\ Μαρία\ Live)\ STAR\ CHANNEL\ 'www.facebook.com_tus.h.tusis'\ [j8evM82JQTk].webm
TUS\ -\ (Φώτης\ και\ Μαρία\ Live)\ STAR\ CHANNEL\ ＂www.facebook.com⧸tus.h.tusis＂\ [j8evM82JQTk].webm
Tus\ &\ Χαρά\ Βέρρα\ -\ Μαργαρίτες\ (Fus\ RMX)\ ｜\ Tus\ &\ Xara\ Verra\ -\ Margarites\ \ (Fus\ RMX)\ [ZbJ9y_g1Gug].webm
Tus\ -\ Χειροβομβίδα\ ft\ Πωλίνα\ -\ Official\ Audio\ Release\ [5cUpE4e1thw].webm
Tus\ -\ χόρτο\ ρε\ βλάκα\ ｜\ Tus\ -\ xorto\ re\ vlaka\ [7eAt1LR8oCc].webm
Tus\ -\ Ψυχανάλυση\ Prod.\ Dennis\ Cage\ [qF31-0C7Now].webm
Tus\ -\ Деньги\ да\ Prod\ Slavic\ Boys\ TM\ -\ Official\ Video\ Clip\ [kZHk7jzcv3U].webm
Tus\ -\ 母親\ -\ Prod.\ Dennis\ Cage\ -\ Official\ Video\ Clip\ [9aKmlSYjSvo].webm
Vibrator\ ｜\ Son\ Of\ The\ Beats\ [2fUf-DA6Tlk].webm
ΑΚ-47\ -\ 'Αλφα\ Κάππα\ (Tus,\ Αρχο)\ ｜\ AK-47\ -\ Alfa\ Kappa\ (Tus,\ Arxo)\ -\ Official\ Audio\ Release\ [6H-WVcGrJTA].webm
ΑΚ-47\ -\ \ Η\ καλύτερη\ μέρα\ για\ να\ πεθάνεις\ (Tus,\ Άρχο)\ -\ Official\ Audio\ Release\ [84-6QG-wtOg].webm
ΑΚ-47\ -\ Κιλά\ (Tus,\ Αρχο)\ ｜\ AK-47\ -\ Kila\ (Tus,\ Arxo)\ -\ Official\ Audio\ Release\ [EaEBPI0Jglo].webm
ΑΚ-47\ -\ Κομμάτια\ (Tus,\ Άρχο)\ -\ Official\ Audio\ Release\ [LM_ktSiwmS4].webm
ΑΚ-47\ -\ Πάνω\ Στο\ Κ＊υλί\ (Tus,\ Αρχο)\ ｜\ AK-47\ -\ Pano\ Sto\ K＊vli\ (Tus,\ Arxo)\ -\ Official\ Audio\ Release\ [guhXF56CZGs].webm
ΑΚ-47\ -\ Πέρα\ στους\ πέρα\ κάμπους\ (Tus,\ Άρχο)\ -\ Official\ Audio\ Release\ [vsIo39dXAUA].webm
ΑΚ-47\ -\ Στον\ Πυθμένα\ (Tus,\ Άρχο)\ -\ Official\ Audio\ Release\ [UjE5oc_togg].webm
ΑΚ-47\ -\ Το\ κρίμα\ στον\ λαιμό\ σου\ (Tus,\ Άρχο)\ -\ Official\ Audio\ Release\ [_IULOiX9uDw].webm
Αντώνης\ Γαμπιεράκης\ -\ Είτε\ τότε\ είτε\ τώρα\ ft\ Ματθαίος\ Γιαννούλης\ &\ Tus\ -\ Prod\ Fus\ -\ Video\ Clip\ [YmhR82DYeeE].webm
Γιάννης\ Μαυρίδης\ ft.\ TUS\ -\ Θεσσαλονίκη\ -\ Official\ Video\ Clip\ [e6D6P277LSc].webm
Γιάννης\ Μαυρίδης\ &\ Tus\ -\ Πόσο\ του\ μηνός\ -\ Official\ Audio\ Release\ [Z7Yw_AsE2uA].webm
Γιώργος\ Λιάτης\ ft.\ Tus\ -\ Η\ πιο\ ωραία\ στην\ Ευρώπη\ I\ Giorgos\ Liatis\ ft.\ Tus\ -\ I\ pio\ oraia\ stin\ evropi\ [fAOoqtWiMWc].webm
Η\ Tus\ ή\ Tusis\ Productions\ σας\ εύχεται\ καλές\ γιορτές.\ [i2Bfb6g_huI].webm
Λευτέρης\ Πανταζής\ feat.\ Tus\ -\ Έρωτας\ ｜\ Lefteris\ Pantazis\ feat.\ Tus\ -\ Erotas\ [L7tcmHQveBY].webm
Λευτέρης\ Πανταζής\ feat.\ Tus\ -\ Έρωτας\ ｜\ Lefteris\ Pantazis\ feat.\ Tus\ -\ Erotas\ [P9aOpLZAMyA].webm
Νάντια\ Αγγελέτου\ ft.\ TUS\ -\ Έτσι\ γουστάρω\ -\ Official\ Video\ Clip\ [Wb-NX1HL9QE].webm
Νέο\ Video\ Clip\ έρχεται\ στις\ 08_11_2013\ [JcGjTbAuPc4].webm
Νέο\ Video\ Clip\ έρχεται\ στις\ 08⧸11⧸2013\ [JcGjTbAuPc4].webm
Νέος\ TUS\ έρχεται\ στις\ 20_10_2013\ [LS19odeY1Do].mkv
Νέος\ TUS\ έρχεται\ στις\ 20⧸10⧸2013\ [LS19odeY1Do].mp4
ΠΡΩΤΟΣ\ ΣΤΟ\ ΣΧΟΛΕΙΟ\ ΕΡΧΕΤΑΙ\ 11-9-2014\ [rGree3k0NJ8].webm
Σώτης\ Βολάνης\ &\ Tus\ -\ Δε\ Με\ Αγαπάει\ -\ Official\ Audio\ Release\ [epF3uIc-E0g].webm
Τus\ &\ Cenobite\ -\ an\ me\ krazeis\ piso\ apo\ to\ pc\ sou\ [NA5VhF1ilBc].webm
Τουσοντίνος\ (TusonaS)\ -\ Η\ Πιο\ Λιώμα\ Στην\ Ελλάδα\ ｜\ Official\ Video\ Clip\ 2015\ [XOpFJMsKuA4].mkv
Χάρης\ Ακριτίδης\ Feat\ \ TUS\ –\ Ψυχοθεραπεία\ [NhjU3ROHyCc].webm
Χάρης\ Ακριτίδης\ Feat\ TUS\ –\ Ψυχοθεραπεία\ \ -\ Official\ Video\ Clip\ [ky3QOkinD4k].webm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `grep` (but would work if you add the `-z` switch):

```
find -type f -name '*｜*' -exec cp {} ident/ \;
```

Comment: thanks! worked like a charm!  can you explain why "\"?

Comment: @Estatistics: it escapes the semi-colon, i.e. the terminator for the `-exec` parameter. From the findutils.info manual: `-exec command ;`. Because the semi-colon is also a command separator in most shells, it needs to be escaped with a backslash.

Comment: @Estatistics: You can find the section of the manual with this command: `info find 'actions' 'run commands' 'single file'`.

Answer (score 0):

the `-i` option is missing at the `xargs` command (see `man xargs`).

```
find . -type f -print0 | grep -i "｜" | xargs -i -0 cp {} ident/
```

I an not sure what you try to do with the `grep`

without the `grep` it would be just the `find`:

```
find . -type f -exec cp -v {} ident/ \;
```

or if I interpret the `grep` correct it might be this:

```
find . -type f -iname '*|*' -exec cp -v {} ident/ \;
```

see `man find`

Comment: 1st says binary file matches. do nothing. 2nd/3rd says  find: argument to '-exec' is missing. thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the "\;" at the end of find. The message "binary file matches" comes from the "grep" which I copied from your question and you did not explain the reason for the grep in your question.